# Getting Microsoft Graph Drive items by path using the .NET SDK

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

As it is [documented](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_list_children), using the Microsoft Graph REST API you can (among other options) get an item by Id or Path. This works fine, as expected:

```
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/children
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/children
```

Using the .NET SDK, I can get a folder by Id (i.e. the first case):

```
var items = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[myFolderId].Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

However, I couldn't find how (using the .NET SDK) to do the same, but specifying a path instead of an Id (i.e. the second case).

I don't want to find an Id of a path I already know, to create the request for it. Right?

I'm afraid is not possible to do this using the current SDK (Microsoft Graph Client Library 1.1.1)?

Comment: Try to use [Microsoft Graph Client Library 1.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/). It works with folder ID.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how:

```
var items = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
                  .ItemWithPath("/this/is/the/path").Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

Use just the plain path. Don't include the ":", and don't include the "/drive/root:/".

it was obvious, now that I see it...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for the organization's drive/SharePoint site. The folder's ID (which should be found first) seems to be the only way to go. :(

Comment: I find my TeamDrive (and its ID) first using the Group API and then you can use: `var childItemsPage = await graphClient.Drives[teamDriveId].Root                                                .ItemWithPath(folderPath).Children.Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: Can we get example what to keep in "/this/is/the/path"?

Comment: What is disappointing is that as of today, March 20,2023 Microsoft's documentation still doesn't have an example of this complex operation using C#. I figured it out using the GraphExplorer but translating to the api was difficult.

Comment: @BrandonG did you find a solution, how to do it after upgrade to SDK 5? Struggling with the same problem...

Comment: @Uriil please review my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76426372/593214

Answer (score 4):

For version 5 I did the following:

```
 results = await graphClient
                .Drives["{ENTER_DRIVE_ID_HERE}"]
                .Root
                .ItemWithPath("{PATH_YOU_CARE_ABOUT}")
                .Children
                .GetAsync();
```

In my use case I needed to iterate over all files in a given folder on a shared drive. I can't remember how I found the drive id but I used the Graph Explorer to find it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Microsoft Graph SDK with Office365 for Business/Sharepoint/Teams, replace the "Me" in the code with "Groups[teamId/groupId]".

Like this:

```
var items = await graphClient.Groups["teamId/groupId"].Drive.Root
    .ItemWithPath("/this/is/the/path").Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

If you use the Microsoft Graph Explorer, you can find out your Team/Group Id:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: How do you get the path of the DriveItem in the first place?