# Identify OneDrive Sync File

Tags: macos, winapi, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I am developing a cross platform desktop application that works with local files. I am now integrating with onedrive/sharepoint through the Microsoft Graph REST API to open files, modify and upload back. My application required single writer, so in order to protect against concurrent editors, we are utilizing the check out/check in functionality of Microsoft Graph REST API.

For users that have onedrive desktop sync. If they open a document through a local path i would like to identify this file as being onedrive sync'd so i can issue checkout/checkin through the Microsoft Graph REST API.  You can see a similar behavior from the office application when opening sync'd file. Although they do not checkout/checkin they do auto save back and retrieve metadata from onedrive based on the HTTP traffic.

So my question is how do i get more details about the file so i can properly make the REST calls? The id/path and the drive id of the item are critical

For Windows, I see there have been [new file attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) added in Windows 10 through the `GetFileAttributes` win32 method. Such as, `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS`.  I can't seem to find anything to retrieve drive item id or drive id

For Mac, what are my options on mac?

Comment: With Graph API you can get items using their path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965330/getting-microsoft-graph-drive-items-by-path-using-the-net-sdk isn't that sufficient?

Comment: So [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) attribute can help you confirm if it is a OneDrive sync file, right? Which REST API do you want to call?

Comment: I understand I could use the path of the file but that is predicated on identifying the root directory that is sync’d to one drive. How do i identity the onedrive root on the local machine? I would like to call the checkout endpoint then over the course of the app lifetime create upload sessions, when the user is done with the file then call check in. The other option I have is to just let the file be saved back to disk instead of uploading I suppose.