# Graph API: modify content of file inside directory

Tags: .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload a file to some SharePoint directory using .NET. So far I can upload it to the root:

```
var fileItem = new DriveItem
{
    Name = "test3.txt",
    File = new Microsoft.Graph.File
            {
            },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename"}
            }
};

await graphClient
    .Sites["*****.sharepoint.com"]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(fileItem);

var sites = await graphClient
    .Sites["*****.sharepoint.com"]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children["test3.txt"].Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

I can **CREATE** file inside folder:

```
await graphClient
    .Sites["*****.sharepoint.com"]
    .Drive
    .Root.Children["New Folder3"]
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(fileItem);
```

But when I try to add content to that file(inside directory):

```
await graphClient
        .Sites["*****.sharepoint.com"]
        .Drive
        .Root
        .Children["New Folder3"]
        .Children["test.txt"].Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

I catch **ResourceNotFoundException** exception.

Comment: You can try using the 'ItemWithPath' method and specify the path as said in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965330/getting-microsoft-graph-drive-items-by-path-using-the-net-sdk) or it would be better  giving the id rather than using the Folder name or file name and use it according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-updating-an-existing-file)

Comment: Glad to here that it worked for you. Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the 'ItemWithPath' method and specify the path as said in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965330/getting-microsoft-graph-drive-items-by-path-using-the-net-sdk) or it would be better giving the id rather than using the Folder name or file name and use it according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-updating-an-existing-file).